# Как реализовать алгоритм открытия пустых ячеек в Сапер?

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

Как реализовать алгоритм открытия пустых ячеек в Сапер?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Чтобы реализовать автоматическое вскрытие пустых ячеек, следуйте таким инструкциям:**

Если пользователь попал на пустую ячейку (`0`), делаем следующее:

- Объявите метод/функцию `open_zeros()`.
- В нём заведите *двумерный bool-массив* `isOpen[N][N]`, для того чтобы предотвратить *stackoverlow*.
- Теперь непосредственно копаем пустые ячейки через рекурсию. Выходить за границы поля нельзя. Если, например, вы походили на координату `A0` (самая левая вверху), то должны идти по такому направлению: вправо, вниз, вниз и вправо. А если где-то посередине, то идем по всему периметру и так рекурсивно. Примерный код проверок:

  ```
        if (X == 0 and Y == 0)
   else if (X == 9 and Y == 0)   
   else if (X == 9 and Y == 0)
   else if (X == 9 and Y == 9)   
   else if (X != 0 and X != 9 and Y == 0)  
   else if (X != 0 and X != 9 and Y == 9) 
   else if (X == 0 and Y != 0 and Y != 9)
   else if (X == 9 and Y != 0 and Y != 9)  
   else
  ```

Наведу пример, что писать в `if'е`:

```
    if (X == 0 && Y == 0)
    {
        if (field[X][Y + 1] != FLAG) // внизу
        {
            field[X][Y + 1] = HiddenField[X][Y + 1]; // значение скрытого присваиваем видимому
            if (HiddenField[X][Y + 1] == 0 && isOpen[X][Y + 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X][Y + 1] = true; // помечаем как уже открытый
                open_zeros(X, Y + 1); // вызываем самого себя
            }
        }
             
        if (field[X + 1][Y] != FLAG) // вправо
        {
            field[X + 1][Y] = HiddenField[X + 1][Y];
            if (HiddenField[X + 1][Y] == 0 && isOpen[X + 1][Y] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X + 1][Y] = true;
                open_zeros(X + 1, Y);
            }
        }
        
        if (field[X + 1][Y + 1] != FLAG) // вниз и вправо
        {            
            field[X + 1][Y + 1] = HiddenField[X + 1][Y + 1];
            if (HiddenField[X + 1][Y + 1] == 0 && isOpen[X + 1][Y + 1] == false)
            {
                isOpen[X + 1][Y + 1] = true;
                open_zeros(X + 1, Y + 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это обычный поиск в ширину. Его можно делать рекурсивно, можно нерекурсивно. Можно с использованием доп массива, можно без использования. Много вариантов в общем.